# Power series(e^) in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

How to prove the sum 
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{2\pi inx}}{n}$ 
converges for any x $\notin$ $\mathbb{Z}$ ?
Thanks.

Comment: I'd try using Dirichlet's test for convergence.

Comment: Well, I know $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$,$b_n=e^{2\pi inx}$, but how to prove that$|\sum_{n=1}^N b_n| \le M$?

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^Ne^{2\pi inx}=\frac{e^{2\pi ix}-e^{2\pi i(N+1)x}}{1-e^{2\pi ix}}$ using the formula for summing a geometric series, and this expression is bounded by $\frac{2}{|1-e^{2\pi ix}|}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x\in\mathbb{Z}
 $ obviously we have $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{e^{2\pi inx}}{n}=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n}=\infty
 $$ if $x\notin\mathbb{Z}
 $ we observe that, from the Taylor series of the complex log $$\textrm{Log}\left(1-z\right)=-\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{z^{n}}{n},\,\left|z\right|<1
 $$ that $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{e^{2\pi inx}}{n}=\color{red}{-\textrm{Log}\left(1-e^{2\pi ix}\right)}.$$